# Present tense during past for vividness

Tags: past-tense, backshifting

> The first technique is prevention of distraction.  I remember at the
>   age of 15, I got my first computer. I was so fascinating for it, I
>   spent so much time on my computer until my stomach growls, my eye
>   hurts, and my finger numbs.

This is a part of the speech I will be given. Is it grammatical to use present tense here: "my stomach growls, my eye hurts, and my finger numbs", so that it sounds more vivid?

Comment: You have your answer below, but the clause before it should be: "I was so fascinated by it".  Unless the computer found you really interesting instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical to use present tense - the form is called the [Historical Present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). But you need to be consistent and write the entire sentence in present tense - you have the past tense verb forms 'was' and 'spent'. Change them to present tense 'am' and 'spend'.

There are other mistakes in your speech but I am focusing on tense.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the **habit** or scene that happened every time. The choice is the modal verb 'would' there.

Said that...

> ...I spent so much time on my computer until my stomach ***would*** growl, my eyes hurt, and my finger numb.

Comment: Thanks, but why not "my stomach would growl, my eyes would hurt, and my finger would numb"? this looks more symmetric.

Comment: Ah, technically yes! :)

Answer (score 0):

The change of tense in a narration written in past tense to a passage in present tense is a literary device with the effect of hightening the depiction of a scene. By changing to present tense you reduce the distance just as in films when the camera changes the distance and brings a scene in close-ups.

Your example is a bit cumbersome. You can't begin a sentence with past tense and continue in present tense. The transition from past to present tense is often done in an artful manner. And then a longer dramatic scene is given in present tense, not only a sentence or clause.